# Get value from EditText in custom layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a my main activity that created a button and also implements a custom layout from within the xml. The xml is this

```
        <com.android.control.MinutePicker
            android:id="@+id/MinPick"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </com.android.control.MinutePicker>
```

The java that this is referencing is as follows. It creates an edittext and also a 2 buttons.

```
but1 = new Button( context );
but1.setTextSize( TEXT_SIZE );
but1.setText( "-" );
but2 = new Button( context );
but2.setTextSize( TEXT_SIZE );
but2.setText( "-" );
valueText = new EditText( context );
valueText.setTextSize( TEXT_SIZE );
valueText.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL );
valueText.setText(0);
this.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
LayoutParams elementParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( ELEMENT_WIDTH, ELEMENT_HEIGHT );

    addView( but1, elementParams );
    addView( valueText, elementParams );
    addView( but2, elementParams );
```

But how do I then obtain the value within the edittext as in the xml there is no explicit mention of the edittext or an id. I tried to reference it via the id of the custom layout and was unsuccessful. Could anyone point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2):

DO you mean getting the text from the EditText?

You created it and assigned it to `valueText`, so use `valueText.getText()`

Comment: but can I call valueText from the parent activity. As nowhere within that activity is anything defined about the edittext or other buttons